# i want while loop for date 2018-03-28 to 2018-04-02 in unix

Tags: shell-script, date

i want while loop syntax in UNIX for date 2018-03-28 to 2018-04-02

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226229/bash-looping-through-dates
which I found with a google search for "bash looping dates". I'm unclear what you mean by UNIX. "can you please help me" tends to annoy people because it makes them think "why should I help you".

Answer (score 4):

Edited to use `YYYYMMDD` output format rather than `YYYY-MM-DD` format, according to user's wishes in comments, and add start date and end date variables, also taken from comments.

Assuming GNU `date`:

```
startdate='2018-03-28'
enddate='2018-04-02'

enddate=$( date -d "$enddate" +%Y%m%d )  # rewrite in YYYYMMDD format
i=0
while [ "$thedate" != "$enddate" ]; do
    thedate=$( date -d "$startdate + $i days" +%Y%m%d ) # get $i days forward
    printf 'The date is "%s"\n' "$thedate"
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

Alternatively:

```
startdate='2018-03-28'
enddate='2018-04-02'

enddate=$( date -d "$enddate + 1 day" +%Y%m%d )   # rewrite in YYYYMMDD format
                                                  #  and take last iteration into account
thedate=$( date -d "$startdate" +%Y%m%d )
while [ "$thedate" != "$enddate" ]; do
    printf 'The date is "%s"\n' "$thedate"
    thedate=$( date -d "$thedate + 1 days" +%Y%m%d ) # increment by one day
done
```

Output:

```
The date is "20180328"
The date is "20180329"
The date is "20180330"
The date is "20180331"
The date is "20180401"
The date is "20180402"
```

Comment: can you help me on remove the - form date  i want to be print date like 20180328 in this format

Comment: @sunil Use `%Y%m%d` instead of `%F`.

Comment: then output is going to infinite.. can you help me to remove - while print and write a input in other file –Kusalananda

Comment: @sunil if you change the date format, you will need to change the string that it is tested against in the inequality correspondingly

Comment: i have one more doubt  :- while im using below code its going to infinite, please help me :- 
#!/bin/bash


i=0
thedate="2018-03-28"
enddate="2018-04-02"
while [ "$thedate" != "$enddate" ]; do
    thedate=$( date -d "$thedate + $i days" +%F )
    
    new_date=$( date -d "$thedate " +%Y%m%d )
    printf 'The date is "%s"\n' "$new_date"
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done     and output should be The date is "20180328"
The date is "20180329"
The date is "20180330"
The date is "20180331"
The date is "20180401"
The date is "20180402"

Comment: @sunil See updated answer.